# LibGDX: How to handle Touchpad input?

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I know that you can just write a code like this in the render method:

```
 public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    myStage.act(delta);
    myStage.draw();

    if(myTouchpad.isTouched()){
         //do stuff
     }else{
         //do different stuff
     }
}
```

But I don't think it's a good way to solve this, is there a way to handle this using listeners or something like that?

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use it with a `Stage` and `Table` as intended?

```
Stage stage = new Stage();
Table table = new Table(skin); // You can skip table and add it directly to the stage as well.
Touchpad touchpad = new Touchpad(deadzoneRadius, skin);

stage.addActor(table);
table.add(touchpad);

Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage); // Stage will handle all input and updates for you.
```

Then you can just use the touchpad methods for whatever you need. If you need to be alerted when the touch pad is pressed you could use a listener.

```
touchpad.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
        // This is run when anything is changed on this actor.
        float deltaX = ((Touchpad) actor).getKnobPercentX();
        float deltaY = ((Touchpad) actor).getKnobPercentY();
        ...
    }
});
```

There are several listeners available ([listener superclass javadoc](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/EventListener.html), lists all listeners), but for a `Touchpad` a `ChangeListener` is probably best suited for the task.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ChangeListener`:

```
touchpad.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
     @Override
     public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
        //do your things
     }
  });
```

Add the listener in your `show()` or `create()` method or in the `screen`'s constructor and you're done!